# Shared session table has two entries in the table for the native and laravel apps

Tags: php, database, laravel, session

I have a native PHP app which authentication part is handled. I save the session to data base there.

```
public function write($sessionId, $sessionData)
    {
       // echo 'write called';
        try {
            $currentTime = time();
            $payload = base64_encode($sessionData);
            $userId = isset($_SESSION['login_RegNo'])? $_SESSION['login_RegNo'] : null;
            $ip = $this->getIP();
            $userAgent = $this->getUserAgent();
            $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("REPLACE INTO sessions (`id`, `last_activity`, `payload`, `user_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("sisiss", $sessionId, $currentTime, $payload, $userId, $ip, $userAgent);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            //echo base64_decode ($payload);
 
            return TRUE;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
           // echo 'write exception';
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

I have a link (`<a>` tag) to the laravel app from this native app.
I have configured the same session table to the laravel app.

.env file

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_CONNECTION=mysql
SESSION_DOMAIN=
```

session.php

```
  'table' => 'sessions',
```

But When I click on the link a different entry is created in the table. Like in the picture.
[image: sesion table]
I am new to the php ann laravel. Can someone explain what have I done wrong?

Comment: The first thing to catch the eye here is how different the "format" of those two session IDs appears to be. The first one contains upper and lower case letters, the second one only lowercase. Laravel might apply different restrictions on what it considers to be a "valid" session id, than native PHP.

Comment: Also a possibility perhaps, that your PHP session cookie is simply not visible to the Laravel app, or using a different name, so that Laravel will start a new session because of that.